# Disable real time search if term is blank - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onkeyup, debouncing

I created a real-time search using [this](https://alligator.io/angular/real-time-search-angular-rxjs/) tutorial but my end point redirects if I send a blank search in the query.  How can I disable my function if my keyup is blank?

Keyup in my html:

```
<input(keyup)="searchTerm$.next($event.target.value)">
```

Component:

```
this.searchService.search(this.searchTerm$)
.subscribe(results => {
  this.results = results
});
```

Search Service:

```
constructor(private http: Http) { }

search(terms: Observable<string>) {
return terms.debounceTime(400)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(term => this.searchEntries(term));
}

searchEntries(term) {
return this.http
    .get(this.baseUrl + this.queryUrl + term)
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just short-circuit:

```
<input (keyup)="$event.target.value && searchTerm$.next($event.target.value)">
```

"If there is a value, then run the search"

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a `filter` operator to the Obserable.

```
return terms.debounceTime(400)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .filter(term => this.term)
  .switchMap(term => this.searchEntries(term));
}
```

Since white space could be an issue you might make the filter a little bit more specific with an expression like `this.term && this.term.trim().length > 0`.  The implementation is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
return terms.debounceTime(400)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(term => this.searchEntries(term));
}
```

You could check the case you wish to disable. So you would change it like this:

```
return terms.debounceTime(400)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(term => {
      if(term){
         this.searchEntries(term);
      }
  });
}
```

There may be a more elegant solution, but that should work.